# What is the point of diverging functions in Rust?

Tags: function, rust, panic

I have read several answers on SO already, and gathered these use-cases:

- When a function `panic!`s
- When a function has an infinite loop in it

But it is still unclear to me why we need to define the function like this:

```
fn func() -> ! {
    panic!("Error!");
}
```

if it will work the same way as this (without the exclamation sign):

```
fn func() {
    panic!("Error!");
}
```

and at the same time, why do we need to use `!` in functions with infinite loops? It look like this signature doesn't bring any real usage information.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The main difference between these signatures boils down to the fact that `!` can *coerce* into any other type, and thus is *compatible* with any other type (since this code path is never taken, we can assume it to be of any type we need). It's important when we have multiple possible code paths, such as `if-else` or `match`.

For example, consider the following (probably contrived, but hopefully clear enough) code:

```
fn assert_positive(v: i32) -> u32 {
    match v.try_into() {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(_) => func(),
    }
}
```

When `func` is declared to return `!`, this function [compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec87afb899764a459235f0b88107b431) successfully. If we drop the return type, `func` will be declared as returning `()`, and the compilation [breaks](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eca1afc8670150ef71dff1f16e6e08e5):

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
 --> src/main.rs:8:19
  |
6 | /     match v.try_into() {
7 | |         Ok(v) => v,
  | |                  - this is found to be of type `u32`
8 | |         Err(_) => func(),
  | |                   ^^^^^^ expected `u32`, found `()`
9 | |     }
  | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
```

You can also compare this with [definition for `Result::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.58.0/src/core/result.rs.html#1292-1297):

```
pub fn unwrap(self) -> T {
    match self {
        Ok(t) => t,
        Err(e) => unwrap_failed("called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value", &e),
    }
}
```

Here, [`unwrap_failed` is returning `!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.58.0/src/core/result.rs.html#1608-1614), so it unifies with whatever type is returned in `Ok` case.

Comment: It seems to me like `!` lets us to achieve something like dynamic typing. But at the same time, this doesn't work: `fn func() -> ! { 123 }`, although you said that __! can coerce into any other type, and thus is compatible with any other type__

Comment: You're trying to do the opposite - coerce `i32` (the default integer type) into `!`. This obviously can't work. "Compatibility" here is one-directioned - "value" of type `!` (non-existant by definition) can be used wherever any other type is expected, not the other way around.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work like dynamic typing is that "!" is a promise that the function will NEVER return. Because of that, we can pretend it would have returned whatever type we want; this will never cause a problem since it never returns. That's why your example isn't allowed. Because it's not _actually_ dynamic typing.

Comment: @AleksandrNovik: This has nothing to do with dynamic typing. `!` is a *bottom type*, not a dynamic type, i.e. it is a type which is a subtype of every other type.

Answer (score 14):

The compiler knows that anything that follows a diverging expression (w.r.t. evaluation order) is unreachable. It can use this information to avoid false negatives when it comes to deciding whether a local variable is initialized or not.

Consider the following example:

```
use rand; // 0.8.4

fn main() {
    let foo;
    if rand::random::<bool>() {
        foo = "Hello, world!";
    } else {
        diverge();
    }
    println!("{foo}");
}

fn diverge() {
    panic!("Crash!");
}
```

We declare a variable `foo`, but we only initialize it in one branch of the `if` expression. This fails to compile with the following error:

```
error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `foo`
  --> src/main.rs:10:15
   |
10 |     println!("{foo}");
   |               ^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `foo`
```

However, if we change the definition of our `diverge` function like this:

```
fn diverge() -> ! {
    panic!("Crash!");
}
```

then the code successfully compiles. The compiler knows that if the `else` branch is taken, it will never reach the `println!` because `diverge()` diverges. Therefore, it's not an error that the `else` branch doesn't initialize `foo`.